# Пустой экран json-сервер с ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Пытаюсь реализовать приложение на ReactJS с использованием [json-сервера](https://github.com/typicode/json-server).  Захожу на localhost:3001 и localhost:3000 - пустота. Где я допустил ошибку?

Порядок моих действий:

Создаю проект

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
$ cd my-app
```

Устанавливаю сервер

```
$ npm install -g json-server
```

Запускаю сервер и приложение

```
$ json-server --watch db.json --port 3001
$ npm run start
```

А затем настройка App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = "http://localhost:3001/posts"
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        let posts = data.map((post, index) => {
          return (

            <div key={index}>
              <h3>{post.title}</h3>
              <p>Tags: {post.tags}</p>
            </div>

          )
        })
        this.setState({posts: posts});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.props}
      </div>
    );
  }
    }

export default App;
```

Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: а какая нибудь ошибка есть в консоли? я думаю дело в CORS...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опечатка `{this.state.props}`, вместо `{this.state.posts}`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = "http://localhost:3001/posts"
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        let posts = data.map((post, index) => {
          return (

            <div key={index}>
              <h3>{post.title}</h3>
              <p>Tags: {post.tags}</p>
            </div>

          )
        })
        this.setState({posts: posts});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.posts}
      </div>
    );
  }
    }

export default App;
```